# Enabling session cookies in a pluggable protocol handler

Tags: internet-explorer, session-cookies, bho, pluggableprotocol

We've implement our own Asynchronous Pluggable Protocol handler which we use to load HTML documents into Internet Explorer from our own document store. We need to be able to store and retrieve session cookies using `document.cookie` in documents loaded into the browser using our APP.

However, when we set `document.cookie` and then check the value, it is always set to an empty string. I guess we need to implement some additional interface but I haven't found any information that might indicate what we are missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/827644/en-us

Locate the following registry key:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings
```

Create a new key `PluggableProtocols`

Add a new string value.

Type the name of the pluggable protocol that you want to enable to access cookies, and then press ENTER.

E.g. if your protocol is `chill://` enter "chill" as the name.

Note that the key might also have to be created under

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings
```